# How to embed numbers values in a Date function in php then get difference?

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have a file in which i have to calculate the total hours of the time spent.
But the problem is that the data i am receiving is broken into Hours and Minutes.
I am converting it to the date() function and then find the difference with PHP built-in time_diff() function. But not succeeded yet..
Kindly help....
**Here is my Data i am Fetching:**

```
$HoursIn = $ls[$j][2];               // Punch-In Hours (e.g: 09)
$MinutesIn = $ls[$j][3];            // Punch-In Minutes (e.g: 38)
$TimeIn = $HoursIn.":".$MinutesIn; // Punch-In Total Time (e.g: 09:38)

$HoursOut = $ls[$j][4];                 // Punch Out Hours (e.g: 17)
$MinutesOut = $ls[$j][5];              // Punch Out Minutes (e.g: 44)
$TimeOut = $HoursOut.":".$MinutesOut; // Punch-Out Total Time (e.g: 17:44)
```

**I have tried this:**

```
$HoursIn = 09;               // Punch-In Hours (e.g: 09)
$HoursIn->format('%h');
$MinutesIn = 38;           // Punch-In Minutes (e.g: 38)
$MinutesIn->format('%i');
$TimeIn = $HoursIn.":".$MinutesIn; // Punch-In Total Time (e.g: 09:38)

$HoursOut = 17;                 // Punch Out Hours (e.g: 17)
$HoursOut->format('%h');
$MinutesOut = 44;              // Punch Out Minutes (e.g: 44)
$MinutesOut->format('%i');
$TimeOut = $HoursOut.":".$MinutesOut;

echo $interval = $TimeOut->diff($TimeIn);
```

But getting fatal Error...

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: You will get a fatal error, you're trying to use an integer as though it was a DateTime object.... combine to get your time as you were doing originally, then convert that '09:38' and '17:44' to datetime objects, then diff them

Comment: You'll also have problems with `09`.... PHP will treat a number with a leading zero as an octal value, and you can't have a `9` digit in an octal number

Comment: Getting this Error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www

Comment: @Mark Baker How to convert this to DateTime object?
$TimeIn;   // Results: 0:38
$TimeOut; // Results: 17:44
And yes I am getting '0' instead of '09'

Comment: `$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Hi', $HoursIn . $MinutesIn); echo $start->format('H:i:s');`

Comment: @MarkBaker see my answer below please (in the answers area..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MarkBaker I have done this with your help! Thanks!
I got the result like this:

```
$HoursIn = $ls[$j][2];         // Punch-In Hours
$MinutesIn = $ls[$j][3];      // Punch-In Minutes
$timein = gmdate('H:i:s', $HoursIn*60*60+$MinutesIn*60);

$HoursOut = $ls[$j][4];        // PunchOut Hours
$MinutesOut = $ls[$j][5];     // PunchOut Minutes
$timeout = gmdate('H:i:s', $HoursOut*60*60+$MinutesOut*60);

$time1 = new DateTime($timein);
$time2 = new DateTime($timeout);
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);           
$interval->format('%H:%i');
```

But Now I want to put a condition but the condition is not working: (I want to make $interval= 00:00 but this if condition is not working...)

```
if($timeout == "00:00:00") {$interval->format('%0:%0');}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are my solution. The result for a sample is 1 hour and 3 mins. Hope it is clear but if any questions - ask me:

```
<?php
$in_time=sprintf("%04u-%02u-%02u %02u:%02u:02u",2015,5,6,12,5,0); // Values : Year Month Day hour min sec
$out_time=sprintf("%04u-%02u-%02u %02u:%02u:02u",2015,5,6,17,8,0); // Values : Year Month Day hour min sec
$TimeIn = new DateTime($in_time);
$TimeOut = new DateTime($out_time);

$interval = $TimeIn->diff($TimeOut);
echo $interval->format('%h:%i');
?>
```